# C# Can I name an array using an integer?

Tags: c#

```
int L = 2;
int M = 0;
for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i++)
{
   foreach (char c in ListLines[L]) 
   {
      if(c == 'A')arrayOne[M]++;
      if(c == 'B')arrayTwo[M]++;
      if(c == 'C')arrayThree[M]++;
   }
   L =+ 2; 
   M++; 
}
```

Hi! 
I'm learning C# at the moment, and I'm trying to create a for loop for my arrays.
All I need to know really is can I create an integer (`int M`) and use that to define the object in the array? For example, `arrayOne[M]`?
As this will allow me to create a counter for it that will let me create a loop.

Comment: what loop do you want to create? what does `M` represent? why are you using that instead of the existing loop variable `i`? what does "same outputs for every object" mean? please show _exactly_ the input for the code, and explain exactly what the output is and how that's different from what you wanted. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: How about a jagged array `int[][] array`. So you can access it like `array[1][M]++`.

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can use indexing on your arrays without problem, as for why you always get the same output, we would need to see the declarations of your arrays.

But in your case, it will make more sense to use a Dictionary instead of multiple arrays.
See: http://csharp.net-informations.com/collection/dictionary.htm

As requested below, here is an example with a Dictionary:

```
var charDict = new Dictionary<char, int>

for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i++){
    foreach (char c in ListLines[i]) {
            charDict[c]++;
        }
    }
```

Note: This does not behave the same way as your code, since I honestly didn't get your code logic.

Comment: An example of using a Dictionary to solve this would make this a good answer.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. The work is actually coursework, so I've decided against posting the whole thing- as all I really needed was a pointer in the right direction regarding using an integer inside the brackets as aMarks[M] rather than aMarks[1].

Comment: Yes there is nothing wrong with your usages of the array. Also if you are using Visual Studio, or any descent c# compiler, you can consider that if you didn't have an error at compilation, then it's fine (not meaning you can't have exceptions at runtime, but your code syntax is legal).